# RoutingError in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

I keep running across this error for a GET request to show action.

```
  1) ShopController GET 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'show', :id=>@shop.user.nickname
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:id=>"picardo", :controller=>"shop", :action=>"show"}
     # ./spec/controllers/shop_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My routes look like this.

```
  #routes.rb
  resources :shop, :only=>[:show]
```

This is the controller spec:

```
  #shop_controller_spec.rb
  before(:each) do
    @shop = Fabricate(:shop)
  end
  describe "GET 'show'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'show', :id=>@shop.user.nickname
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

And teh controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(:first,:conditions=>{:nickname=>params[:id]})
    @shop = @user.shop
  end
```

Comment: Any word on this? I'm having this most simplest of problems too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some rails rules.
If you have a singular resource you have to write `resource :shop` and if you have the  plural resources you have to write `resources :shops`. You can run `rake routes` command to see the difference.

You wrote `resources :shop` and request sends to `ShopController` that is not exist in your application because I am sure that controller named `ShopsController`. Because the another rails rule is to name controllers in plural form and models in singular.

Or just write a controller name in routes: `resources :shop, :controller => 'shops'`